# Why is <sys/types.h> blkcnt_t a signed value if it measures number of blocks?

Tags: posix

In the refs related to `<sys/types.h>` the type `blkcnt_t` is defined as:

> **blkcnt_t**
>       Used for file block counts.

also it states:

> **blkcnt_t** and off_t shall be signed integer types.

(see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html#tag_13_67)

I was unable to find the rationale for the number of blocks ever being negative, hence I wonder why the type is defined signed?

While I cannot imagine well the use of files having a *negative* number of blocks, I would think that blkcnt_t might be assigned a *negative* value to signify some sort of error/exceptional condition?

Fun fact is that the blkcnt_t type was introduced as unsigned (see [here](http://marc.info/?t=114339657200020&r=1&w=2)) and
then later changed to be signed (see [here](http://marc.info/?l=cygwin-patches&m=146851069329496&w=2)). As description/rationale why this change happend this commit message is given:

> "blkcnt_t and off_t shall be signed integer types." This
>   causes pacman to fail when the size requirement of the net update
>   operation is negative, instead it calculated a huge positive number.

Comment: You're comparing two different codebases here. The first link is the Linux kernel, the second one cygwin. blkcnt_t is still unsigned in the Linux kernel: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/types.h#L131.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine it’s signed to support signed arithmetic, or rather storing signed block count deltas (which is what [tripped up `pacman`](https://git.archlinux.org/pacman.git/commit/?id=8ffa2b24a5e3d63d6f34a1257ed67904ec051e3d) and prompted [the Cygwin patch](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-patches/2016-q3/msg00007.html) you mention).

In the Linux kernel it is still [still unsigned](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/types.h#n131).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just for backwards compatibility. In earlier versions there was no `blkcnt_t` type but the field had simply been `long`. So when they moved to a more flexible specification they probably wanted to keep the signedness of the field.